# Showing $ ( T(p) )(x) = p'(x) + p(0) \cdot x^n $ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant

**Problem:** Let $ V = \mathbb{C_n}[x] $ be the polynomial space of degree at most $n $. We define a linear transformation $ T: V \to V $ as $ ( T(p) )(x) = p'(x) + p(0) \cdot x^n $.
Prove this transformation is diagonalizable.

**Attempt:** We'll denote $ e = ( 1,x,x^2 ,...,x^n ) $ as a basis for $ V $. Then,$ T(1) = 0 , T(x) = 1 , T(x^2 ) = 2x , T(x^3) = 3x^2 ,\dots , T(x^n) = n\cdot x^{n-1}$.
Thus, the matrix representation of this linear transformation with respect to basis $ e $ is,$ [T]_{e}^{e} = ​\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 2 & \ldots & 0 & 0\\\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\0 & 0 & 0 &\ldots & 0 & n \\0 & 0 & 0 &\ldots & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} $

[ Here I stopped]

When I tried finding eigenvalues I got $ | [T]_{e}^{e} - \lambda \cdot I | = ​\begin{vmatrix} -\lambda & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -\lambda & 2 & \ldots & 0 & 0\\\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\0 & 0 & 0 &\ldots & -\lambda & n \\0 & 0 & 0 &\ldots & 0 & -\lambda \end{vmatrix} = ( -\lambda )^n = 0 \rightarrow \lambda = 0  $

Which means $ T $ is not diagonalizable. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hello :) We have $T(1) =x^n$

Comment: I feel so ashamed... I spent a few hours on this problem.. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :)